# Arduino - use print(.., DEC) to save into variable

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, variables

I am using:

```
Serial.print(rawCodes[i - 1], DEC);
```

to print into serial monitor, but how can I save `(rawCodes[i - 1], DEC)` to save into variable?

Comment: The string value or the integer value of `rawCodes[i-1]`? How is `rawCodes` declared?

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt rawCodes is unsigned int

Comment: `rawCodes` is *already* a variable. What do you actually want to *achieve*?

Comment: @Majenko I want get rawCodes[i - 1] to int variable

Comment: ***NO!!!*** That is what you *think* you want to *do*. Not *what the end result is that you desire*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your code comes from here: https://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/08/19/how-to-hack-any-ir-remote-controller/

Since `rawCodes` is declared as

```
unsigned int rawCodes[35];
```

I.e., it is a 35-element array of `unsigned int` elements, we can access a single `unsigned int` element at some index and save it in a variable like

```
unsigned int myVariable = rawCodes[i - 1]; //assuming i is some integer variable 
                                           //and exists in this scope
```

If conversion to a `String` object is needed it can be passed into the constructor of the `String` class as

```
String myString = String(myVariable);
```

That answers your syntactical question on how to save that element into a variable; however, it is unlikely that this is your real underlying problem. We cannot determine that until you tell us what exactly you actually want.

References:

- [Arrays in C tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm)